# Our application no longer starts when using the new Hibernate 6 release

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-6.x

I see that hibernate 6 came out recently so I took some time to try to convert our app to use it (we had been running the 5.6.7.Final before).

We had to go through the migration guide and make some changes such as using the new @Type annotations style (which is much nicer).  After a bit of work everything compiled and I could at least run the app.

The problem I am having now is the app never finishes initializing hibernate.  It uses all of my CPU and never finishes starting.  I figured I would attach a profiler and found that the app is stuck running in an infinite loop calling FetchParent.generateFetchableFetch

[image]

Comment: If I leave it running awhile I eventually get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.

Comment: If you still have that problem with the latest Hibernate version 6.1.7 or 6.2.0.CR2 then please create an issue in the issue tracker(https://hibernate.atlassian.net